# Bash: Serve a file through tcp

Tags: bash, tcp

I should write a function which deals with two parameters.

- the path of a file to be deployed (as $ 1) and
- the port number of the port on which the content of this file is output (as $ 2)

The function should then make the contents of this file available to the first program that connects to it via TCP. The function is not intended to run anything important in the background and to abort once the file content has been streamed. Be careful not to run a function in the background that could block a specific port.

But I have no clue how to deal with that.

Test case

```
echo -e "five\nsix\nseven" > $WORK_DIR/testfile.txt
servelines $WORK_DIR/testfile.txt 7777 &
sleep 0.1
RESULT=$(nc -d 127.0.0.1 7777)
[[ "$RESULT" == $(cat $WORK_DIR/testfile.txt) ]] || (echo "received results should be 'five six seven' but are '$RESULT'" && false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command called `nc` (netcat) that allows you to send data over a TCP connection.

In order to serve the data you have to use the `-l` flag to instruct it to act as a server. It serves the data sent through stdin.

Your script can look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -l $2 < $1
```

You might need to install `nc`, so make sure you have it.

netcat is actually really useful, so you should take some time to read the manual page (run `man nc`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I abort the connection after the first stream of the file? Do I need to use -N for this?

Comment: `nc` will terminate after the first stream.

Comment: Hmm.. because my given test case won't terminate. If I add -N as well, it is terminating.

Comment: I added the test case to my first post

Comment: @Julian your test case is successful for me with `-N`, like you said. In a perfect world, you'd make sure to wait on the child process you spawned as well.